# sem_wait never returns a return value

Tags: c++, linux, wait, semaphore, sem

I am trying to create a lock using `sem_wait()` and I have a `printf` before and after the `sem_wait` call. (I do not see this being printed: `printf("after sem wait ");`) The `sem_wait` call never returns.

```c
sem_t* sem;
Thank you
int 32_t retVal = -1;
printf("before sem wait ");
retVal  = sem_wait(sem);
printf("after sem wait ");
```

How do I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `sem_wait` must to point to an actual `sem_t` object which you've initialized using `sem_init`. For example:

```c
sem_t sem;
sem_init(&sem, 1);
printf("before sem wait\n");
sem_wait(&sem);
printf("after sem wait\n");
sem_destroy(&sem);
```

Of course if you're using this object for actual signalling, you'll also need to arrange to call `sem_post()` elsewhere to increment the semaphore.